# Show welcome page when correct credentials are entered?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this code that logs  a user in:

```
function logUserIn(){
    var email = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorMessage)
      console.log('didnt log in')
    });
  };
```

this is the html:

```
          username:<br>
          <input id="username" type="text" name="username" ><br>
          password:<br>
          <input id="password" type="text" name="password" ><br><br>
          <input type="submit" onclick=logUserIn() value="Log in">
          <input type="submit" onclick=submitToDatabase() value="Sign Up">
          <input type="submit" onclick=getUsers() value="Get Users">
```

how can I then submit this data using only javascript so if they enter the right credentials it takes them to page such as welcome.html?
I understand I may need to use a form and submitting, but I wasn't sure how this is done in JS alone and not using PHP.
I want it to say Welcome User (user being the email they signed in with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to check for errors, and then proceed to a redirection.

Here is the sample code from Firebase documentation:

```
// Sign in with email and pass.
// [START authwithemail]
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(user) {
  console.log(user);
  // DO YOUR REDIRECTION HERE
}).catch(function(error) {
  if(error) throw error;
});
```

For more informations. The `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method returns a firebase.Promise.

> signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) returns firebase.Promise containing non-null firebase.User

You can read more here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise#then

For the redirection you can use `Location.replace()`. Here is a doc. link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Hope this helps !

Comment: it doesn't seem to get inside the second if part. is that because it only goes into the function if it has an error?

Comment: Hey, sorry ! I updated the code to meet your needs, should work.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `onAuthStateChanged()` to keep track of the user's login or logout status.

```
//Handle Account Status
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    window.location = 'welcome.html'; //If User is logged in, redirect to welcome page
  }
});
```

The above code will make sure that if a user successfully signs in, they are redirected to welcome page.